# SQL query to find result set with english and other translated words

Tags: sql, oracle, join

2 tables are as `Eng` & `Tr` which contain following data-

```
Eng table:-                                      Tr table:-

sn   val1                                         sn  val2   trns
--   ---                                          --  ---    ----
 1   one                                          2   zwei    de
 2   two                                          2   dos     es
 3   three                                        3   drei    de
 4   four                                         4   cuatro  es
 5   five                                         4   quatro  it
```

I want to get result of values having translated as German language (`DE`) along with which not translated (like 1, 5 as well). So I want output like below -

```
sn  val1   val2
--  ---    ----
 1  one    
 2  two   zwei
 3  three drei
 5  five
```

Comment: its easy join these 2 table & filter by language as `de`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join:

```sql
SELECT e.sn, e.val1, t.val2
FROM Eng e
LEFT JOIN Tr t
    ON t.sn = e.sn AND t.trns = 'de';
```

Note that from SQL's point of view, both `one` and `four` are really the same in that neither has a translation available in German.  My answer therefore reports both of them.